# How to do I close print dialog boxes?

Tags: perl, modal-dialog

I searched different modules for closing the print dialog but I haven't got anything which will work on all platforms.

Can anyone help me about the Perl modules which will check for already opened print dialog boxes and closing them through the code?

Comment: Actually I am testing a site, When i do the click on one button it gives the print dialog that i am not able to handle from selenium so i am searching for alternative which can be handled from perl.

Comment: In that case, don't you just need to interact with the print dialog for the browser you are using from Selenium on the platform you are running selenium on? Rather than all applications on all platforms?

Comment: actually selenium will interact with only the browser not with system print dialog boxes as you know i guess. I have a common code to run on all platforms except this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this module helps you:

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GuiTest](http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aGuiTest)

If not, just search for some general 'win gui testing' or 'win32 ui automation' module.

... and this as a 'last aid': http://www.autohotkey.com/
I used it when I need to close modal dialog of compiler when I was automatizating compilation.

On Linux, you could use

wmctrl - http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/

for controlling several kind of window managers

Comment: Oh, you are right, so at least 'half' of the question aswered.

Comment: Even this module also i tried but i want for all platforms. I am also looking into it.